# With OpenOffice's Impress, how to use original image size?

Tags: images, openoffice-impress

I'm creating a slide show with Impress, each one is a image from a file, when it's is played, the images are enlarged, how to set them so that when it plays them, the images are displayed as the original size ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried right-clicking on the image, selecting "Original Size", then right-clicking again, going to "Position and Size", and checking the "Size" checkbox in the "Protect" area?  (Unfortunately, I only have LibreOffice. :-( )